# How do I take a specific subset in a row of a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, plot, standard-deviation

I´m using a DataFrame with global temperatures along earth´s story to see climate change hypothesis.
I´m interested in searching for information about Spain and they have lots of information, so I decided to discard the monthly data and use anual information instead.

How do I select the information of the first of January for each year? I was able to discard the other countries and take information from 1900 in advance.

Secondly, how can I create a vertical line to express standard deviation based on the `AverageTemperatureUncertainty` column?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

glt_by_country = pd.read_csv("GlobalLandTemperatures_GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry.csv")
glt_b_count_df = pd.DataFrame(glt_by_country)

glt_spain = glt_b_count_df[(glt_b_count_df["Country"]=="Spain") & (glt_b_count_df["dt"] >= "1900-01-01")]
print(glt_spain)
glt_spain.plot(x = "dt", y = "AverageTemperature", kind = "line")

plt.show()
```

The dataset contains 4 rows, `date, AverageTemperature, AverageTemperatureUncertainty,Country`.

`date`should be stepping for year to year and `AverageTemperatureUncertainty`should be shown as a vertical bar in the line plot to see the deviation.